# Use popen with a relative or absolute path on Windows in C

Tags: c, windows, video, ffmpeg, popen

I'm trying to a GUI wrapper for FFmpeg. I decided to build my program around the binary instead of the libraries. I want to call ffmpeg.exe in parallel to my program and get the console output instantly to parse it and show to the user a progress bar or something.

So I found `popen` which sends me the output when it comes so I can do what I want with it. But there are some problems with paths in `popen` on Windows.

When I try `ffmpeg.exe -i TEST.mkv TEST.mp4` (when I'm in the folder of both ffmpeg.exe and my source file either from start or a chdir) it works well and I get what I want.

But when I do

> `bin/ffmpeg.exe -i TEST.mkv TEST.mp4`

(with the executable obviously being in the `bin` folder) it doesn't find the command `bin`:

> `'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

It also doesn't work with quotation marks around the path:

> `"bin/ffmpeg.exe" -i TEST.mkv TEST.mp4`

But it does work with an absolute path and quotation marks:

> `"C:/PATH/TO/USER/FFmpeg GUI/bin/ffmpeg.exe" -i jellyfish.mkv jellyfish.mp4`.

But it gets funnier.

If I use relative paths for the source and output, it works.

> `"C:/Users/tibtw_000/Raccourci/Code/FFmpeg GUI/bin/ffmpeg.exe" -i videos/jellyfish.mkv videos/jellyfish.mp4`

But if I want to put an absolute path to my source or output files, it now doesn't work.

> `"C:/PATH/TO/USER/FFmpeg GUI/bin/ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:/PATH/TO/USER/FFmpeg GUI/videos/jellyfish.mkv"`

and now returns

> `'C:/PATH/TO/USER/FFmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Now I'm starting to wonder if the space in my path is at fault. And it was. When I use

> `C:/PATH/TO/USER/FFmpegGUI/bin/ffmpeg.exe -i C:/PATH/TO/USER/FFmpegGUI/videos/jellyfish.mkv C:/PATH/TO/USER/FFmpegGUI/videos/jellyfish.mp4` in popen everything works perfectly.

So what should I do? Do I force the user to not put his files in paths with spaces? Is there a special character that I can put instead of a normal space in the path to make `popen` understand what I want it to do?

Comment: Tried using the back slash `bin\ffmpeg.exe` instead of the forward slash?

Comment: I made a simple executable `ffmpeg.exe` and placed it in a folder called `bin`. In a Windows console, when I run it from the parent folder with `bin\ffmpeg.exe` it outputs "Hallo from ffmpeg" but when I run it with `bin/ffmpeg.exe` the system replies "'bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Oh dear! I didn't even try this, it works! I'll try backslashes in a path with spaces and I'm coming back to you. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you have a string literal the backslash needs to be "escaped" with another like `"\\"`.

Comment: Yes I did this. But now I still have my main problem. Paths with spaces don't work. I tried "C:\PATH\TO\USER\FFmpeg GUI\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "C:\PATH\TO\USER\FFmpeg GUI\videos\jellyfish.mkv" and it still can't understand the command. :/

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Oh well. So could you explain what command you are trying and how you did it in C please?

Comment: I made a folder with a space in its name. I wrote a program that prints out its given arguments, and placed it in that folder. I ran it from a different folder with the full path in quotes, and arguments in quotes. It printed the arguments correctly.

Comment: Rule #1 for file handling: Do not ever use relative paths. As for your immediate problem: `popen` is the wrong tool. Use `CreateProcess` instead, if sanity is something you want to keep.

Comment: That's why I wanted to use absolute paths in the end. But I wanted to be precise in my post so I tested what I could. Ok thanks I'll look into it! :)